# Exclude more then one date

Tags: datetime

I'm new to Drupal. I'm trying to make a work calendar.

I need to make weekly events in the calendar. And that's working real well but now I want to exclude dates from an event.

Is there a way to select more than one date at time?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 possible approaches, as further explained below (I'm assuming you're using Drupal version 7, not 6).

## Use a boolean field to exclude from the calendar

For the content types that you want to include in your calendar, add a boolean field like "Exclude from Calendar" (Y/N). When creating your view, filter out the nodes that have a value of "Y" for this field.

## Use 'Views Contextual Filters OR'

Consider module [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) (which only has a dev version today). Excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR conditions for contextual filters.

With that, you might be able to specify the various dates to be excluded, with something like date1 OR date2 OR ... (if you only have a few dates to be excluded o course).

Does this help?